# How to correctly project texture to UV map from 3D scanned object?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, 2d, texture-coordinates

I am a beginner in Blender and I am trying to get a 2D image of a scanned object with the texture correctly applied or projected.

As you can see, in the right section I have the 3D object with its texture applied. It is an OBJ file product of a 3D scan.
[image: Capture_1]
As I was investigating, one way to obtain a projection is through a UV map ("Mark seam" => "Unwrap"). When doing it, I get a 2D object with the desired shape (selected in orange, left section), but the texture is not applied correctly, it is shown in the background without projecting on the faces.

Is there any way to achieve it?
[image]